# numerical differentiation with Scipy

Tags: numerical, derivative

I was trying to learn Scipy, using it for mixed integrations and differentiations, but at the very initial step I encountered the following problems.

For numerical differentiation, it seems that the only Scipy function that works for callable functions is scipy.derivative() if I'm right!? However, I couldn't work with it:

**1st)** when I am not going to specify the point at which the differentiation is to be taken, e.g. when the differentiation is under an integral so that it is the integral that should assign the numerical values to its integrand's variable, not me. As a simple example I tried this code in Sage's notebook:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate, derivative
var('y')
f=lambda x: 10^10*sin(x)
g=lambda x,y: f(x+y^2)
I=integrate.quad( sp.derivative(f(y),y, dx=0.00001, n=1, order=7) , 0, pi)[0]; show(I)
show( integral(diff(f(y),y),y,0,1).n() )
```

also it gives the warning that "Warning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved. The error may be underestimated." and I don't know what does this warning stand for as it persists even with increasing "dx" and decreasing the "order".

**2nd)** when I want to find the derivative of a multivariable function like g(x,y) in the above example and something like sp.derivative(g(x,y),(x,0.5), dx=0.01, n=1, order=3) gives error, as is easily expected.

Looking forward to hearing from you about how to resolve the above cited problems with numerical differentiation.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some strange problems with your code that suggest you need to brush up on some python! I don't know how you even made these definitions in python since they are not legal syntax.

First, I think you are using an older version of scipy. In recent versions (at least from 0.12+) you need `from scipy.misc import derivative`. `derivative` is not in the scipy global namespace.

Second, `var` is not defined, although it is not necessary anyway (I think you meant to import sympy first and use `sympy.var('y')`). `sin` has also not been imported from math (or numpy, if you prefer). `show` is not a valid function in sympy or scipy.

^ is not the power operator in python. You meant **

You seem to be mixing up the idea of symbolic and numeric calculus operations here. scipy won't numerically differentiate an expression involving a symbolic object -- the second argument to derivative is supposed to be the point at which you wish to take the derivative (i.e. a number). As you say you are trying to do numeric differentiation, I'll resolve the issue for that purpose.

```
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.misc import derivative
from math import *

f = lambda x: 10**10*sin(x)
df = lambda x: derivative(f, x, dx=0.00001, n=1, order=7)
I = integrate.quad( df, 0, pi)[0]
```

Now, this last expression generates the warning you mentioned, and the value returned is not very close to zero at -0.0731642869874073 in absolute terms, although that's not bad relative to the scale of `f`. You have to appreciate the issues of roundoff error in finite differencing. Your function `f` varies on your interval between 0 and 10^10! It probably seems paradoxical, but making the `dx` value for differentiation too small can actually magnify roundoff error and cause numerical instability. See the second graph here ("Example showing the difficulty of choosing h due to both rounding error and formula error") for an explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

In fact, in this case, you need to *increase* it, say to 0.001: `df = lambda x: derivative(f, x, dx=0.001, n=1, order=7)`

Then, you can integrate safely, with no terrible roundoff.

```
I=integrate.quad( df, 0, pi)[0]
```

I don't recommend throwing away the second return value from `quad`. It's an important verification of what happened, as it is "an estimate of the absolute error in the result". In this case, I == 0.0012846582250212652 and the abs error is ~ 0.00022, which is not bad (the interval that implies still does not include zero). Maybe some more fiddling with the dx and absolute tolerances for quad will get you an even better solution, but hopefully you get the idea.

For your second problem, you simply need to create a proper scalar function (call it `gx`) that represents g(x,y) along y=0.5 (this is called Currying in computer science).

```
g = lambda x, y: f(x+y**2)
gx = lambda x: g(x, 0.5)

derivative(gx, 0.2, dx=0.01, n=1, order=3)
```

gives you a value of the derivative at x=0.2. Naturally, the value is huge given the scale of `f`. You can integrate using quad like I showed you above.

If you want to be able to differentiate g itself, you need a different numerical differentiation functio. I don't think scipy or numpy support this, although you could hack together a central difference calculation by making a 2D fine mesh (size dx) and using numpy.gradient. There are probably other library solutions that I'm not aware of, but I know my PyDSTool software contains a function `diff` that will do that (if you rewrite g to take one array argument instead). It uses Ridder's method and is inspired from the Numerical Recipes pseudocode.

Comment: Thank you RHC, actually I had forgotten that I have asked such a question :) The reason the syntax seems odd goes back to the fact that I used to use python from within the Sagemath and, yes, you're right, I was trying to mix numerical and analytical calculations and if my memory helps it didn't work and further I didn't need to use it as the symbolic differentiation was almost as fast as numerical differentiation, quite the opposite of the symbolic integration which was too slow compared to numerical integration. Meanwhile, thanks for taking time answering the question.